# BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans. where to initialize the beanfactory?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am trying create small login application using spring MVC and security.I understand from the error message that the bean factory should be initialized to access the beans.I am trying to understand where should I do that? Requesting your help in this issue.

Pl find the below jsp & XML files for reference.

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<web-app xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" version="2.4" id="WebApp_ID">
<display-name>Spring MVC</display-name>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/pages/hello.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

 <listener>
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>
        /WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml,
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml 
        </param-value>
</context-param>
 <filter>
<filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
</filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

spring-security.xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">
    <http auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/welcome*" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <http-basic />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
          <user-service>
            <user name="rahul" password="123" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
          </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<beans xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
<context:component-scan base-package="test"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>mymessages</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
</beans>
```

login.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="/WEB-INF/tld/c.tld"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login Page</title>
<style>
.errorblock {
    color: #ff0000;
    background-color: #ffEEEE;
    border: 3px solid #ff0000;
    padding: 8px;
    margin: 16px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body onload='document.f.j_username.focus();'>
    <h3>Login with Username and Password (Custom Page)</h3>

    <c:if test="${SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION !=null}"><!-- ${not empty error} -->
        <div class="errorblock">
            Your login attempt was not successful, try again.<br /> Caused :
            ${sessionScope["SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION"].message}
        </div>
    </c:if>

    <form name='f' action="<c:url value='j_spring_security_check' />"
        method='POST'>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>User:</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='j_username' value=''>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password:</td>
                <td><input type='password' name='j_password' />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan='2'><input name="submit" type="submit"
                    value="submit" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan='2'><input name="reset" type="reset" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

hello.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="/WEB-INF/tld/c.tld" %>
<html>
<body>
    <h3>message : ${message}</h3>
    <h3>User name : ${username}</h3>
    <a href = "<c:url value="/j_spring_security_logout" />">LogOut</a>
</body>
</html>
```

home.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Welcome to spring security</h3>
    <a href="/SpringSecurity1-FORM/welcome"><b>Click here to logon</b></a>
</body>
</html>
```

Error Log

```
WARNING: Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close
java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Wed Jul 12 15:07:11 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:416)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:997)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:581)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4980)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5626)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Jul 12, 2017 3:07:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStop
SEVERE: Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.getBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:170)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1028)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1004)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:581)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4980)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5626)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Please add logs.

Comment: In a spring web application, contextConfigLocation context-param gives the location of the root context. The root context in a spring application is the ApplicationContext. So if your question is where to initialize it, i would say in your mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

Comment: @ Sangam Belose : I have appended logs.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

@RBz : It is working now. As you said, 
1)I initialized the bean in mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml.

2)Added the missing jar files & added necessary spring jar files of the same version.

Regards